# Schematic utils are not available anymore in @angular/core since version 15.1.0

Tags: angular

I'm working on a design-system for my company and thanks to the power of Angular Schematics, we were able to provide an automated migration workflow to our devs, to upgrade the design-system from version 4 to 5.

In said updates we're dependant on the **angular schematics utilities** that were available in the npm package **@angular/core** up to version **15.0.4** in the /schematics/utils folder.
 Unfortunately, these are **no longer available** since version **15.1.0**.

My question is therefore:
Was this intentional?
And if the answer is "yes", is there a way to use this utils from somewhere else?

I could not find any information about it in the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md).

The utilities should still/again be released to the npm package so that they can be imported and used with the path `@angular/core/schematics/utils/[util-name]`.

Comment: As for the first part of your question, I think you can only get a sound answer from the Angular dev team itself. Hence you're probably better off asking this on Github.

Comment: You're probably right, but I just wanted to follow their contribution rules ;)
If I don't get an answer in the next few days/weeks, I will open a topic on github.